# Pass Data from One .exe to Another

Tags: python, c++

I'm relatively inexperienced with C++, but I need to build a framework to shuffle some data around. Not necessarily relevant, but the general flow path of my data needs to go like this:

1. Data is generated in a python script
2. The python object is passed to a compiled C++ extension
3. The C++ extension makes some changes and passes the data (presumably a pointer?) to compiled C++/CUDA code (.exe)
4. C++/CUDA .exe does stuff
5. Data is handled back in the python script and sent to more python functions

Step 3. is where I'm having trouble. How would I go about calling the .exe containing the CUDA code in a way that it can access the data that is seen in the C++ python extension? I assume I should be able to pass a pointer somehow, but I'm having trouble finding resources that explain how. I've seen references to creating shared memory, but I'm unclear on the details there, as well.

Comment: You need to do some research on IPC (Interprocess communications) mechanisms.

Comment: have you looked at C++ bindings for python? You can call a C++ class/method/function from within python

Comment: You can not pass a pointer as the address is only valid for the owning process.

Comment: The most common methods are named pipes and memory mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *many* ways two executables can exchange data.

Some examples:

- write/read data to/from a shared file (don't forget locking so they don't stumble on eachother).
- use TCP or UDP sockets between the processes to exchange data.
- use shared memory.
- if one application starts the other you can pass data via commandline arguments or in the environment.
- use pipes between the processes.
- use Unix domain sockets between the processes.

And there are more options but the above are probably the most common ones.

What you need to research is IPC (Inter-Process Communication).

Comment: Websocket or RESTful with CppRest (Casablanca)

Comment: @Ceros that's just sockets (as I already mentioned) just with an extra protocol layer on top.